# Win10へのCaboChaインストールについて

Tags: windows, windows-10, 自然言語処理, cabocha

Win10でCaboCha0.69の実行の際以下のようなエラーが発生して実行ができません

```
morph.cpp(48) [g_mecab_handle != 0] LoadLibrary("C:\Program Files 
(x86)\MeCab\etc\..\bin\libmecab.dll") failed
```

MeCab0.996がインストール済みでutf-8で辞書を構築済み、パスも通してあり実行可能。
CaboChaはexeファイルからutf-8の辞書でインストール。
Cabocha0.53ではインストール後、実行可能ですがutf-8に対応していないので、最新のバージョンで実行したいです。
解決方法やアドバイス、確認すべき箇所等ございましたらお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

64bit版のMeCabをインストールしていませんか？
私も同じ症状が出たのですが、32bit版のMeCabを追加でインストールし解決しました。

32bit版は公式サイトのBinary package for MS-Windowsからダウンロードできます。
インストーラーの指示通りにインストールしてください。

(参考)
公式サイト - http://taku910.github.io/mecab/

Answer (score -2):

公式サイトからBinary package for MS-Windowsをアクセスできません。恐れ入りますが、ファイルをkkhuang1990@gmail.comに送って頂けないでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ。当サイトでは質問に対して「回答」を付けていくサイトであり、一般的な掲示板とは趣きが異なっています。もし困りごとがある場合には、[新しい質問として投稿](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) してみてください。